# boost::enable_if enabler() related to the tutorial on creating an iterator with boost::iterator_facade

Tags: c++, boost

So... looking at this code fragment:

```
    #include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
    #include <boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp>
    #include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
    
    template <class Value>
    class LMI
      : public boost::iterator_facade<LMI<Value>, Value, boost::forward_traversal_tag>
    {
    private:
      int xsize, ysize, x, y;
      Level *level {0};             // iterator invalid if level == 0

    public:
      LMI(LMI<OtherValue> const &L, 
          typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_convertible<OtherValue*,Value*>,
                                    enabler>::type = enabler())
        : xsize {L.xsize}, ysize {L.ysize}, x {L.x}, y {L.y}, level {L.level}
      {};
    };
```

The compiler complains that there is no identifier 'enabler' ... which all comes from the boost example documentation at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#telling-the-truth

I'm at the point where I realize that enable_if and is_convertible are magic templates that determine if this converting constructor is created (which the tutorial as much says), but I don't see any advice on this "enabler()" function --- is the tutorial incorrect in this usage?  Has the usage changed since the tutorial was written?

It may help the readers to know that this template is used thusly:

```
typedef LMI<Tile> Level_Map_Iterator;
typedef LMI<Tile const> cLevel_Map_Iterator;
```

... the point being that while creating LMI it will create the converting constructor and while creating LMI it will not.

Comment: Umm... the definition of `enabler` is given directly in that example. Do you see the line `struct enabler {};`? It's fine to experiment with examples, but keep in mind that if your experiment fails to compile, look first to the parts of the example that you dropped.

Comment: Now I feel dumb.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... sheepishly, if I add

```
struct enabler {};
```

to the private section of the class template, all is good.  Doesn't exactly explain how this works --- but I'm happy with the secret sauce for now.  Obviously, I was adapting the tutorial example to my own work, sigh.

Comment: You could change the question to ask why/how it works... ;) The explanation is not deep, but the syntax of templates can get confusing. (If you want to think about it yourself: the special thing about `enabler` is that it cannot match any type supplied from outside your class.)